# Type inference inconsistency

Tags: scala, generics, collections, containers, type-inference

Let's say I have a wrapper class

```
case class Cont [E] (e : Seq[E]) {
  def :: [E1 >: E] (e1 : Seq[E1]) : Cont[E1] = Cont(e1 ++ e)
  def + [E1 >: E] (e1 : Seq[E1]) : Cont[E1] = Cont(e1 ++ e)
}
```

It is a wrapper over a sequence of some type. It can accept a seguence of another type and return new wrapper for appended sequences now with the type of their supertype. It does that two ways - from right to left with :: and from left to right with +.

Now these are the result of chaining:

```
Cont(Seq[Nothing]()) //-> Cont[Nothing]
Seq[Nothing]() :: Cont(Seq[Nothing]()) //-> Cont[Nothing]
Seq[Nothing]() :: Seq[Nothing]() :: Cont(Seq[Nothing]()) //-> Cont[E1]
Seq[Int]() :: Seq[Nothing]() :: Seq[Nothing]() :: Cont(Seq[Nothing]()) //-> Cont[Any]

Cont(Seq[Nothing]())//-> Cont[Nothing]
Cont(Seq[Nothing]()) + Seq[Nothing]()//-> Cont[Nothing]
Cont(Seq[Nothing]()) + Seq[Nothing]() + Seq[Nothing]() //-> Cont[Nothing]
Cont(Seq[Nothing]()) + Seq[Nothing]() + Seq[Nothing]() + Seq[Int]() //-> Cont[Int]
```

The results should be the same or shouldn't they? They aren't. I need the second (left to right) behaviour. I don't even know what the Cont[E1] means. Is there a reason why this happens? Are there any fixes for the code using ::?

Comment: This seems to be a bug - `Cont[E1]` is not a valid type. Furthermore, `Cont[Nothing]` is enough for the third case and `Cont[Int]` for the fourth case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that method names that end with a colon when used in infix "operator-like" form are right-associative and resolve against the right-hand operand?

In other words:

```
foo :: bar
```

is equivalent to:

```
bar.::(foo)
```

while this:

```
foo + bar
```

is equivalent to

```
foo.+(bar)
```

I believe that explains the difference you're seeing between `+` and `::`.